# Do $S^n$ and $\mathbb{R}P^n$ admit the same number of linearly independent vector fields?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, vector-fields

For a manifold $M$, let $i(M)$ be the maximum possible number of everywhere linearly independent vector fields on $M$. It's evident, I believe, that $i(S^n) \geq i(\mathbb{R}P^n)$. Does the equality hold?

Comment: The answer is yes and was apparently proved in http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/adams2.pdf although it isn't clear to me exactly where

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The quantity $i(M)$ is called the *span* of $M$.

First of all, let's establish the inequality $i(S^n) \geq i(\mathbb{RP}^n)$.

Let $M$ be a connected smooth manifold and $\Gamma$ a discrete group which acts smoothly, freely, and properly. Then $M/\Gamma$ can be equipped with a unique smooth manifold structure such that the projection $\pi : M \to M/\Gamma$ is a smooth covering map. In particular, $d\pi : TM \to T(M/\Gamma)$ is a vector bundle isomorphism covering $\pi$, so $\pi^*T(M/\Gamma) \cong TM$.

A manifold admits $k$ linearly independent vector fields if and only if its tangent bundle is isomorphic to a direct sum of two vector bundles, one of which is trivial of rank $k$. Suppose then that $M/\Gamma$ admits $k$ linearly independent vector fields, that is $T(M/\Gamma) \cong F\oplus\varepsilon^k_{M/\Gamma}$. Then we have

$$TM \cong \pi^*T(M/\Gamma) \cong \pi^*(F\oplus\varepsilon^k_{M/\Gamma}) \cong \pi^*F\oplus\pi^*\varepsilon^k_{M/\Gamma} \cong \pi^*F\oplus\varepsilon^k_M.$$

Therefore $M$ also admits $k$ linearly independent vector fields, so $i(M) \geq i(M/\Gamma)$; that is, the span of a manifold cannot decrease when passing to covers. In particular, for $M = S^n$ and $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}_2$ acting by the antipodal map, we see that $i(S^n) \geq i(\mathbb{RP}^n)$ as you suspected.

For the other direction, note that in chapter I, section $7$ of *Spin Geometry* by Lawson and Michelsohn, they construct $k$ linearly independent vector fields $V_1, \dots, V_k$ on $S^n$ when $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a $Cl_k$-module. Moreover, these vectors fields satisfy $V_i(-x) = -V_i(x)$ and hence descend to $k$ linearly independent vector fields on $\mathbb{RP}^n$.

They then determine the largest $k$ such that $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is a $Cl_k$-module, i.e. the largest number of linearly independent vector fields on $S^n$ (and hence $\mathbb{RP}^n$) which can be constructed this way. It is equal to $\rho(n+1) - 1$ where $\rho(n)$ denotes the $n^{\text{th}}$ Radon-Hurwitz number which is defined as follows: if $n = 2^{4a + b}c$ where $a, b, c$ are non-negative integers, $0 \leq b \leq 3$ and $c$ is odd, then $\rho(n) = 8a + 2^b$. Therefore $i(S^n), i(\mathbb{RP}^n) \geq \rho(n+1) - 1$.

The final piece of the puzzle is the result by Adams which states that there are at most $\rho(n + 1) - 1$ linearly independent vector fields on $S^n$; see Theorem $1.1$ of [this paper](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/adams2.pdf). So we see that $i(S^n) = \rho(n+1) - 1$, and hence $\rho(n + 1) - 1 = i(S^n) \geq i (\mathbb{RP}^n) \geq \rho(n+1) - 1$. Therefore, $i(S^n) = i(\mathbb{RP}^n)= \rho(n+1) - 1$.

---

Adams' result is very difficult, so it may seem that there is a more elementary argument to show that $i(S^n) = i(\mathbb{RP}^n)$. Note however that the equality $i(M) = i(M/\Gamma)$ does not hold in general, so an argument specific to this case was needed. For example, [the two-dimensional torus is a double cover of the Klein bottle](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1073425/39599), and while the torus admits two linearly independent vector fields (i.e. it is parallelisable), the Klein bottle only admits one (it admits at least one as $\chi(K) = 0$, but it can't admit two as it is non-orientable). That is, $i(T^2) = 2$ and $i(K) = 1$, so $i(T^2) \neq i(K)$.